# wrap content of Tiny MCE editor with div

Tags: jquery, html, tinymce

I would like to wrap the content of my Tiny MCE editor with a div, the docs for doing something like this seem vague.

I would like to wrap the content with `<div id="random-wrap"> </div>`

What are my options?

Here is the code I tried to work with

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  var name = "wprsspostprepend";
if($("#" + name).length > 0) {
 $("#wprsspostprepend").addClass("prepend_editor");
  tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector : "prepend_editor"  
});
   var content =  tinyMCE.get("prepend_editor").getContent();
    tinyMCE.get("prepend_editor").setContent("<div id='random-wrap'>" + content + "</div>");
}



});
```

I am trying to do this on wordpress so maybe that is the issue, but I keep getting the error

> Cannot read property 'getContent' of null

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are trying to access the editor content before it fully initialized. it will take some time even after document is ready.

so the best way to use 'init' event as below .
if you want to change content in every change of the editor then use 'change' event instead of 'init'

```
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector : "prepend_editor",     
        setup: function (editor) {
                   editor.on("init", function () {
                        var content = editor.getContent();;
                        editor.setContent(content);
                   });
                }  

)};
```